# Change slowly z-index value after hover has ended on image

Tags: html, css

I have blog post with set of images that are enlarged on hover. My problem is that when i enlarge element and it overlaps with other image that is later in page render order then the next image is on top of the enlarged one.

The easy way to stop this is to give some kind of z-index on :hover pseudo selector. But then i have very pesky problem when just after I stop hovering my image then next one is on top of it for fraction of second.

You can see behaviour in [this imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucdp2.jpg) or on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h94ss2ec/)(hover first image)

In short i have following css for hovering effect:

```
.photo-exp
{
position: relative;
transition: all .4s ease-in-out; 
/* some properties deleted which have no connection to hovering effect */
}

.photo-exp:hover
{
transform: scale(1.7); 
z-index : 10;
}
```

It would be very easy to have same effect with javascript and setTimeout function.

But i would like to avoid javascript solution and have some CSS workaround which will change slowly z-index in time after hovering ends.

I tried CSS transition but it is not working
I tried to eddit [this snippet](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/gboJf) but i could not get it working in the way that i wanted.

Comment: It's absolutely not clear what you want by reading *"CSS workaround which will change slowly z-index in time after hovering ends"* Imagine you're holding in your hands two colored papers, one red one blue. Beside you cannot physically make one go-trough another - now, can you explain the desired magic effect?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan what he is saying is a lot clearer from the jsfiddle.

Comment: My desired behaviour is to make z-index go back to normal after hovering and transition effect will go off. So after my image is back to normal with normal size and no hover effect.

Comment: A pure css solution may be difficult. Maintaining on-hover properties for a duration after the hover has physically ended is a classic problem!

Comment: hard code the z index of the dialog/zoomed img high. toggle the dialog/zoom class on and off. that should avoid a blink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a new `transition-delay` property, and remove it as soon as the hover begins. That way the `z-index` can persist for some time even after the mouse is gone. It's a little counter-intuitive; I would expect that the delay should be *added* on hover and *removed* off-hover but the opposite works on chrome:

```css
.expander {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; top: 50%;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  margin-top: -50px; margin-left: -50px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform 400ms 0ms, z-index 0ms 400ms; /* That final "400ms" delays the z-index transition! */
}
.expander:hover {
  transform: scale(1.8);
  z-index: 2; /* A hovered expander is always on top */
  transition: transform 400ms 0ms, z-index 0ms 0ms; /* Remove the z-index transition delay on hover. This is counter-intuitive but works. */
}
.expander:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: -105px;
  background-color: #a00000;
}
.expander:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-color: #00af00;
}
```

```html
<div class="expander"></div>
<div class="expander"></div>
```

Note that (unless you try to mouse around really quickly in order to break it) neither square bleeds through the other, not even for a frame, when they expand.

Answer (score 0):

I've also finally managed to solve by myself my problem. 
It's more intuitive than @Gershom Maes answer in my opinion.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h94ss2ec/11/)

I have used animation system to achieve the result.

```
@keyframes nohovering {
  0%   { z-index: 9; }
  100% { z-index: 1; }
}

@keyframes hovering {
  0%   { z-index: 10; }
  100% { z-index: 10; }
}
```

First one will be by default fired on selector without :hover like this
`animation: nohovering 0.9s;`

It will guarantee that after i complete my hovering it will go smoothly down from z-index 9 to z-index 1. After hovering my image will be on top of other images. When i tested it for z-index 10 for 0% i had a little glitch when i tried to hovered 2 images at same time and then hover only 1 of them.

For my hovering selector I used:
`animation: hovering 0.1s infinite;`

It will just loop my image on z-index 10. On hover it will always be on top of the other images. Short animation time guarantee that it will go off after hovering stopped in maximum time of 0.1s.

After deleting normal static z-indexes it works.